# Creating smooth transition for a button that reveals hidden span when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have a button that, when hovered over, shows a `<span>` that is otherwise hidden. What I'm trying to figure out is how to transition the button's expansion on `:hover` so it's more smooth. I tried using CSS3 transitions but couldn't quite get it down. Plus I don't know if that's the best solution anyway.

EDIT: I added some jQuery but must have something wrong. Here's the script I used, after reading a previous answer here (which I'll reference if I can find it again):

```
$('a:has(span)').hover(
    function() { $('span', this).fadeIn(); },
    function() { $('span', this).fadeOut(); },
);
```

I've created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UYexr/. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would avoid using CSS3 simply because of its lack of support; given that I would probably stick to JS animation.

The best way I would see to do this is to make the span have `display:inline-block;` with a defined width. Then you can use a javascript animation library to animate the span's display.

Personally, I would go about using jQuery's [animate method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Although there are **plenty** of js animation libraries...

Comment: I want to make sure I understand. Would you give the span `<display:inline-block;>` and a defined width before `<:hover>` or on `<:hover>`? The idea is to show the `<span>` on :hover and have the button's width transition as a result of expanding to show the `<span>`.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some sample code to the Fiddle I linked in the question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EjHbc/28/, that is a partially working example of what I believe you should do. Unfortunately JSFiddle is messing with my jquery; for a full example you should test it locally and include the jquery code. Then replace `.style.display = "inherit"` with `.show("slow")` as outlined [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: and heres a whole question of correct responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379226/jsfiddle-not-working-with-jquery/6379353#6379353

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks for the extra effort!

Comment: No Problem :) But don't thank me, thank the people in that thread and upvote them, their the ones who helped *me*.