# JSFIddle not working with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

While working on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351772/creating-smooth-transition-for-a-button-that-reveals-hidden-span-when-hovered/6352594#6352594) I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Rxc/1/). For some reason it isn't working, and when I used firebug's error consol it was returning that ".show" is not a function. This leads me to believe that jsfiddle is incorrectly loading jQuery. Are there any known issues between JSFiddle and jQuery? Is my code simply incorrect (BTW when I change `.show("slow")` to `.style.display = "inherit"` it works fine which is why I think it has to be a problem with jQuery...)

A working JSFiddle would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not even calling jQuery from that jsfiddle :)

Comment: I love it that everybody is using jsfiddle, makes it so much easier to answer questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You forgot a `}`.
2. You're calling jQuery methods on elements that aren't wrapped in a jQuery object. You would need to do:

```
$(itemName.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]).show("slow");
```

(Note the wrapping). jQuery methods don't magically extend default elements, the object must be wrapped first.

Note now that [this version works](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Rxc/8/).

**EDIT**:

Alternatively, you could use the second parameter of jQuery's construct (scope) and shorten this code:

```
function showy(itemName) {
    $('span:first',itemName).show("slow");
}
function closy(itemName) {
    $('span:first',itemName).hide("slow");
}
```

**EDITv2**

Juan brought up a good point, you should also separate javascript with markup. By this I mean avoid using the on* attributes of the elements, and keep the bindings within the external .js file or `<script>` tags. e.g.

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="http://path.to/jquery.js">
  <script>
    $(function(){ // execute once the document is ready (onload="below_code()")

      // bind to the buttons' hover events
      // find them by the "button" and "white" class names
      $('.button.white').hover(function(){ // hover event (onmouseover="below_code()")

        // find the first span within the link that triggered the event
        $('span:first',this).show('slow');

      },function(){ // mouse out event (onmouseout="below_code()")

        // likewise, find first span
        $('span:first',this).hide('slow');

      });
    });
  </script>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  ...
  <a href="#" class="button white" id="button1">
    <span id="spanToShow">SHOW: this text&nbsp;</span>
    on hover
  </a>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to fix OP's bug; however, I think you should instruct the OP on how to to use jQuery without handlers embedded in the HTML

Comment: thanks, I'm completely new to jquery and the missing bracket was just me failing... anyway you get the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

I modified it to this:

```
function showy(itemName) {
    $(itemName).find("span").show("slow");
}
function closy(itemName) {
     $(itemName).find("span").hide("slow");
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ttweX/

Answer (score 1):

I am *really* not a fan of obtrusive javascript :p

You should get used to never ever using the inline event handlers, and instead use jQuery's event binding.

Better solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ttweX/2/

Also the one Tomh linked does some weird infinite blinking obnoxiousness.

```
$(function(){
    $('a.button').hover(
       function(){
         $(this).find('span').show('slow');
       },
       function(){
         $(this).find('span').hide('slow');
       }
    )
});
```